# ARM Program Counter distinguishing feature

Tags: arm, intel, cpu-architecture

How does the R15 of ARM differ from the general PC of  a CPU? 
Both of them are program counters only. What is the difference?

Answer (score 5):

ARM's PC is more similar to a regular register with some restrictions than x86's IP is similar to a regular register.

Considering general PC is an Intel x86 based CPU, in x86's case you can't manipulate PC (Instruction pointer) directly but it is updated implicitly by provided control flow instructions.

In ARM's case historically Program Counter (PC), mapped as register at index 15 (16th register) can be manipulated directly via arithmetic instructions. For example you can add 16 to PC which would alter flow of instruction stream similar to a 16-byte forward jump instruction.

Comment: @USC to add to this very good answer, it simplifies the instruction set (because a jump is then just an `ADD` to the magic 15th register, instead of an instruction dedicated to this purpose). Two other things make `r15` interesting. It always points 2 instructions ahead of where you'd expect (a legacy of the pipelined design of the earliest ARM cores), and its bottom two bits are special. Because ARM instructions are naturally aligned to 4-byte boundaries, the bottom 2 bits would be always zero; So `r15`'s bit 0 was borrowed to indicate whether the processor is executing in Thumb or ARM mode.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist You should have add that as an answer and please do :)

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist Mitch Alsup (a semi-retired professional computer architect who worked on SPARC at Ross, 88k at Motorola, and x86 at AMD) said: History records that PC in the GPRs is "overly uniform."

Answer (score 1):

The ARM PC maybe more of a general register than most CPUs, but it is still very special.  The traditional simple arithmetic instructions can use the `PC` as an input argument in many cases.   Here it functions as a pointer or array base.  It can also be used as the output for control transfer with these instructions.  As a *read-only* value, it is useful for calculating return values in a PC-independent way.  It is also useful to use as a constant table look-up in near-by code.  For these cases, the `PC` is very much like a regular register.  This is probably more common on many RISC CPUs as opposed to a CISC ISA.

However, when the PC is used as a destination (*lvalue* or updated and written), the behavior is often non-standard.  Some examples of special cases (for some ARM architechure versions) for R15/PC are,

- `adcs` - copies `SPSR` to `CPSR`
- `adds` - copies `SPSR` to `CPSR`
- `ands` - copies `SPSR` to `CPSR`
- `bics` - copies `SPSR` to `CPSR`
- `bx r15` - highly discourage or not supported.
- `clz r15` - not supported.
- `mcr pXX, xx, r15,...` - unpredictable
- *etc.*

In most cases, using the `PC` as a destination of an instruction will have some special case.  Especially, the use of the **S** (normally to set conditions codes) can be used to return from an exception.  This might be used as some sort of *veneer* when returning from an exception or just a direct return.  In some cases, the meaning of the instruction might change completely.  For instance, `ldm sp, {r0-r15}^` and `ldm sp, {r0-r14}^` use different register banks; the first will load the registers according to the mode in the SPSR; whereas the 2nd will load the register to *user mode*.

For load/store, atomics, mode manipulation, co-processor and complex arithmetic (64 bit multiplies, etc) instructions, the `PC` is often unsupported or has a different meaning; the different meaning is often a mechanism for handling exceptions for system level code.

Comment: Some other examples are `bx rN` and `blx label` which have explicit modification of the `R15` register.  The `LR` (R14) is also a little special in the the ARM ISA; each mode has a different banked version of `LR`.  *Thumb* makes the `SP` (R13) intrinsic too.  For pure ARM, any register could be the stack.